# Angular2 form: text input populates with "false"?

Tags: forms, angular, input, data-binding

I have a form to edit instances of a model (modelName). The model has a description field which is a string. The form is set up like this:

```
<label class="form-group">
        <span class="control-label col-md-3">Description</span>
        <span class="col-md-9">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" [(ngModel)]="modelName.description" required />
        </span>
</label>
```

And when the edit form is opened using an instance of the model that has a defined description, the form populates with "false" instead of the description. If I add

```
{{modelName.description}}
```

to the label attached to the description input, it prints the string as expected.

I would like the form input to populate with the description string instead of "false"?

Comment: try removing name="description" attribute

Comment: @Dalibor turns out I accidentally had two inputs with the same name "description".... fixing that solved the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Do I get a upvote? :)